# How to uninstall a pear package?

Tags: php, pear

What is the command to uninstall a pear package?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
pear uninstall [options] [channel/]<package>
```

So if you wanted to uninstall PHPUnit

```
pear uninstall phpunit/PHPUnit
```

Note: remember to preface with `sudo` or you won't have permission to uninstall anything.

Comment: Assuming you installed pear into a root only location.  It's possible to setup pear to use your local user account  (something like ~/PEAR) in which case the sudo isn't needed.

Answer (score 8):

> pear uninstall package_name

You can read about it [here in the PHP Cookbook](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch21_08.htm)

Answer (score 2):

If you're on a RPM Linux Distro, it's simple with [YUM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellowdog_Updater,_Modified)

If you installed a PEAR package with YUM you can uninstall with YUM as well.

```
yum install php-pear-db
```

to install and

```
yum remove php-pear-db
```

to remove.

Comment: The question is: how to uninstall *a* PEAR package, PEAR is a repository of packages. You're answering the question how to uninstall *the* PEAR package, which is a piece of Linux software.

Comment: @NielsBom Yes I understand the difference but some of PEAR's packages can be install with YUM/Apt-Get/etc.. (Other packet managers). So yum remove php-pear* should remove any Pear packages that were install with YUM.

Comment: And how would you then uninstall a _specific_ PEAR package using this command?

Comment: Again let me stress, if you installed a PEAR package with YUM you can uninstall with YUM as well. yum install php-pear-db to install yum remove php-pear-db to remove. The OP never states how they installed the Pear Package this is why I said IF you're on a RPM Linux Distro

Comment: I've edited your answer to include part of your last comment.

Answer (score -1):

**-: Additional :-**

The uninstall command removes a package and accepts a list of installed packages to remove as arguments.

**Plugins** must be explicitly uninstalled with the -p or --plugin option. Plugins are installed into the location specified by the plugins_dir configuration variable, which defaults to the same location that the user configuration file is located ($HOME/.pear in unix, \pear on windows).

```
php pyrus.phar uninstall -p PEAR2_Pyrus_Developer
```